# Why is margin taken into account for absolute positioned elements?

Tags: html, css

Assume the following HTML:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

#item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="item">
  Hello
</div>
```

Since the element is absolutely positioned, I'm expecting the `margin-top` and `margin-left` properties to be ignored here. However, I find the element aligned 20px to the top and 10px to the left. (Using Chrome 77 here)

Can someone provide an explanation as to why/how the margin are taken into account here ?

Comment: The `top` and `left` properties are in reference to the nearest positioned parent (or the `<body>` tag in your case since there's no positioned parent). The margin is applied to the `#item` in your code, so it has nothing to do with that. `#item` is positioned at the `left: 0` and `top: 0` of the `<body>` tag and it has `20px` margins on both its top and left side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS absolute positioned elements and margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373683/css-absolute-positioned-elements-and-margins)

Comment: Why you expect the margin to be ignored? we center absolute with margin (https://stackoverflow.com/q/59723642/8620333)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's what the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) says:

> An absolutely positioned element is an element whose computed position
>   value is absolute or fixed. The top, right, bottom, and left
>   properties specify offsets from the edges of the element's containing
>   block. (The containing block is the ancestor relative to which the
>   element is positioned.) **If the element has margins, they are added
>   to the offset**. The element establishes a new block formatting
>   context (BFC) for its contents.

Also: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position

> ...though absolutely positioned boxes have margins, they do not
>   collapse with any other margins.

Comment: You answered this same question in a comment 6 years ago! ha! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373683/css-absolute-positioned-elements-and-margins

Comment: @disinfor Now with citations! ;)