# CSS Puzzle: how does margin auto + left + right calculation works?

Tags: css, position, margin

I played with this layout: 1 responsive `div` with two equal sections and a purple fixed size `div`, that should be placed responsive in the middle of the left section (no matter how one resizes the browser window the `div.abs` stays in the center of the left section)

One possible solution is shown below (or [here](https://codepen.io/sunsande/pen/OJqXExQ?editors=1100))

The solution

```
left: calc(25% - 20px);
```

is straightforward - take the middle of the first section (50% - 25% = 25% and subtract the half of the `div.abs`).

But if we substitute it with

```
margin: auto;
left: -50%;
right: 0px;
```

it is still working!

Could someone explain how the calculation is done in that case?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid Tomato;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 50vh;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: MediumPurple;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
/*   margin: auto;
  left: -50%;
  right: 0px; */
  left: calc(25% - 20px);
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.left {
  background-color: DarkSeaGreen;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  background-color: PapayaWhip;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="abs"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you specify `left` AND `right` they get averaged out essentially.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to [the Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) and the below formula:

> 'left' + 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' + 'right' = width of containing block

We have no border and padding so we can simplify to:

> 'left' + 'margin-left' + 'width' + 'margin-right' + 'right' = width of containing block

Then the following will apply for your case:

> If none of the three is 'auto': If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', solve the equation under the extra constraint that the two margins get equal values,

So let's solve the equation:

```
left + 2*m + width + right = 100%
-50% + 2*m + 40px + 0 = 100%
2*m = 150% - 40px
m = 75% - 20px
```

Now if you define the margin equal to the above and with that you define either left or right you get the same result:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid Tomato;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 50vh;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: MediumPurple;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  right: 0px; /* or left: -50% */
  margin: 0 calc(75% - 20px);
}

.left {
  background-color: DarkSeaGreen;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  background-color: PapayaWhip;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="abs"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Basically your element is centered between the point "left: -50%" and "right:0". So when you define `margin: auto`, you center the element between the position you define with left and right. That's why centering an element requires left and right to be equal.

Related question: [Why magin:auto is not enough to center position absolute or fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59723642/8620333)

Comment: Thank you VERY much this is a perfect answer!! I've learned something.